# How do I interpret macOS errors printed to the console?

Tags: photos.app, error, console

For some reason, my Photos Library has stopped syncing. In traditional Apple fashion, you don't get a lot of information on the problem in the UI: it says "syncing 38 items to iCloud" and that should be enough for anyone.

No matter -- I'm a programmer (though not a Mac programmer) and I know that I can access more detailed information using the "Console" application. So I did that, and I found an error message that looks very promising.

Here's the problem: I have no idea how to read this. Here's the error message I got, formatted for readability.

Can someone teach me how to read this, where to look up the error codes, etc, so that next time I can solve this issue myself?

Here's an example: the lowest-level error seems to be an `NSURLErrorDomain`, but I don't know how to translate the `-1001` code to an actual root cause.

```
Sync session did fail with error (foreground):
Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=81 UserInfo={
    CPLErrorRequestUUIDs=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x14a74bd30 {
        Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=4 UserInfo={
            NSDebugDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x14a62c300 {
                Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 UserInfo={
                    _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2104,
                    _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>,
                    NSURLErrorNetworkUnavailableReasonKey=1,
                    _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>,
                    NSLocalizedDescription=<private>,
                    NSErrorFailingURLKey=<private>,
                    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<private>,
                    _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
// (there is more here but it looks like a repetition, and has been truncated)
```

Comment: A timeout. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778167/undocumented-nsurlerrordomain-error-codes-1001-1003-and-1004-using-storeki for description of -1001 (and other) error codes.